# How to disable cron service delay on startup?

Tags: server, scripts, cron, services

I'm trying to add the execution of a shell script on server startup. I do it using cron, so I configured it with 'crontab -e' command. It looks so:

`@reboot /home/user/run.sh`

Then I enabled a service with:

`sudo systemctl enable cron.service`

But when I reboot my server, jobs are not started. I check the service status with:

`sudo systemctl status cron.service`

[screenshot with a service status after startup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9lF8.png)

And there is a message that it's 2h 55min left to start executing all jobs. So, as I understood service is running but with 3 hours delay. It's happening after every server startup.

Using sudo `systemctl restart cron.service` command helps to make service working, but the server skips `@reboot` jobs because "it's not system startup".

Comment: Review your logs and .service file to determine the reason for cron's delay.